# Windows 10 Slave Drive not Showing

Tags: windows, windows-10, hard-drive

My computer is fitted with a slave drive and i have a lot of files on it. I just noticed that my slave drive has disappeared and i cannot access it anymore. I went to Disk Management and this is what i see:

[image]

From this it looks like Windows wants me to initialize the disk. If i do initialize, does it matter which option i pick? Will initializing my disk reformat the disk and lose all my files?

If i cancel the Initialize Disk window and follow the recommendation on this thread: [Suggestion from another website](https://ccm.net/forum/affich-26671-second-hard-drive-not-recognized), will it reformat my disk and lose all my files?

Comment: Don't do anything, I would suggest a professional recovery if there is critical data on it, disconnect it from the pc now.

Comment: Here is a do it yourself solution if data is not super critical....https://www.easeus.com/resource/disk-unknown-not-initialized.html

Answer (score -1):

*open file explorer -- then type in the info bar [ says something like 'quick access' Where it says that type THIS PC -  bingo it pops up.*